# Clean Url does not work

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, clean-urls

My program is a web project in asp.net 2008 and I use urlrewriting Module to cleaning my URLs.
For this,I only add some configuration settings in web.config and define some rules in web.config.then in my .aspx file I use clean Urls.
My program has been work in local mode.but when I upload my program in server,it does not work. and my rules does not work properly.
also,My Server is a window server.

can any one help me? This is so force for me.

thanks so much.

Comment: Just a suggestion.why don't you use IIRF?

Comment: Are you using IIS7 urlrewriting Module ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using IIS7 urlrewriting Module, make sure you have installed the module on the server.

[Download URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)